# In the Anglican and Catholic church, are any of man's creative ideas seen as original?

Tags: nature-of-god, nature-of-man

I mean, did Shakespeare invent 'A Midsummer Night's Dream' or was it a reflection of the pre-existing, eternal God? Ditto Dickens and Oliver Twist, ditto Spielburg and Jurassic Park, ditto the Beatles 'Love love me do' and EVERY idea that has ever existed...in so much as they exist (in other words, without any evil that may or may not be with a work- evil and sin being the negation of good, not a creation in itself).

Answer (score 4):

In the view of at least the Anglican and Catholic churches, [man is a creative being](http://www.creationism.org/csshs/v12n2p02.htm). Many theologians consider it part of being '[made in the image of God](http://www.relevantmagazine.com/god/deeper-walk/features/23549-qmade-in-the-image-of-godq)'. There is a difference though - God is the only being that can create 'ex nihilo' (out of nothing). Man can create new things, but he must have raw materials - not just physical ones, like paint and canvas, but also cultural references, musical theory and such like. The faculties that humans use to be creative are also from God. But nonetheless, man does actually create, producing something that did not exist before.

As for the good and evil parts, the general view is that man is not perfect and therefore cannot create any perfect work. All the works you mention (and any you don't) may therefore contain much good, but are not entirely and completely good. This view isn't universally accepted, but it is widespread and cuts across denominational lines.

For more reading, try:

- [The Mind of the Maker, by Dorothy L Sayers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mind_of_the_Maker)
- Modern Art and the Death of Culture, by [Hans Rookmaaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Rookmaaker)
- Various works by Alister McGrath